# Join controller names (Swagger)

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

Is it possible to merge 2 different controls into one when we document in swagger?

from:

```
/api/v1/my_endpoint
/api/v1/my_controller_2/{id}
/api/v1/my_profile/{id}/all
```

to:

```
/api/v1/my_endpoint
/api/v1/my_endpoint/{id}
/api/v1/my_endpoint/{id}/all
```

[Attached example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRPw7.png)

I'm using Swashbuckle (.Net Core)

Comment: What library/framework do you use - Springfox, Swashbuckle, ...? Can you post your existing code?

Comment: Hello, I'm using Swashbuckle.